# Can it damage my Pi to permanently pull down the RUN pin?

Tags: electronics, safety

I have a use-case where I would leave my Raspberry Pi powered up but keep it in the halted state by pulling down the RUN pinout. Is this safe to do?

Edit:
The answer shows me that I did not state my use-case clearly. What will happen is basically this:

- The Pi will be in the same power-grid as some other PC.
- At the start of the day the whole grid will be powered up.
- At the end of the day the whole grid will be powered down.
- Sometimes I want to use the Pi for this day and sometimes the other PC.
- On the days the Pi is not needed I still have to power up the whole grid (and therefore the Pi). The Pi signals other systems to come up when it boots. Since I don't want the other systems to activate I don't want to boot the Pi at all.

I know this is pretty convoluted and I'd rather split up the power-grid but sadly this is not an option (legacy system).

Comment: You don't need to do that to keep it in a halted state.  That's where it is after you shutdown the system.  Leave it plugged in and it is now "powered up" but "in the halted state".

Comment: My guess is the op wants to be able to control when it starts back up again, hence having control over the run pin? But thats just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly save to hold the RUN pin low.

There seems little point, because as goldilocks says it will be in the halt state.

The GPIO pins also retain their state (which can be used by `gpio-poweroff` to signal this state).

It presumably will use less power (which is small anyway) if the RUN pin is low because this will prevent the Video Core from running, (which continues when the processor is halted) and will reset the GPIO.

Comment: Ok, I see that my question is not as clear as I intended. Please note the edit.