# Using Run Pin for Startup on pi zero w and v2

Tags: boot, pi-zero-w, arduino, alternative-power, pi-zero-w-2

I'm planning on running a pi zero 2 connected to an arduino over uart for a personal project, but I'm using a pcb and I want to power it on and off without using any cables.

My current plan is to apply constant filtered power to the 5v pin (pin 2) and ground pin 9 (I'll use 4, 6, 8 and 10 for the uart) and then get a 3 pin switch and have the run pin grounded when the switch is open, and then apply some voltage (not sure how much) to it when the switch is closed.

Will this work? And is there a better way? Also does mean that I'm wasting power (5V is always connected) or does the pi stop drawing power when the pin is grounded?

Comment: Hello & welcome to RPi SE. It would be much better if your question included a schematic to illustrate the interconnections. There is a [schematic tool available here](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2074/how-do-i-add-a-schematic-to-my-question), or you can use an externally-generated schematic & paste it in your question as an image.

Answer (score 0):

No it won't work.

It will certainly stop the Pi BUT unless you do an orderly shutdown you risk corrupting the FS.

The RUN pin should really be labeled RESET (with a bar - indicating active LOW).

See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/91118/8697

Comment: What if I have a system that runs the shutdown command and then grounds the pin. Can I then use the run pin to power it back on?

Comment: Do not ask questions in comments. Edit your question (or ask a new question).